# Scrolling body after dismissing bootstrap 3 modal

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am launching a bootstrap 3 modal on document ready of index.html. I also have a link on about.html like index.html#people which is accessing a section on index.html with id 'people' but when I click index.html#people on about.html the window navigates to index.html but not to the section #people because the modal opens on its document.ready. What should I do to navigate to the people section after dismissal of the modal.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your document ready function, check if there is a hash present in the URL, and if there is, scroll to that element:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    /* 
      Your actual code here
    */
    if(window.location.hash) {
          $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: $("#"+window.location.hash).offset().top
          }, 2000);
    }
});
```